# iOS: System sound previews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I was hoping this would just work. I want to be able to click on the button and each time it plays the next system sound. It doesn't work.

I have a button that does this:

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundNumber);
    NSLog(@"%d",soundNumber);
    soundNumber++;
}
```

N.B. Soundnumber is initialized at 1000 which via [this site](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) should be the new-mail notification.
The NSLog works just fine, but I'm not getting any audio.
Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I don't quite understand the system sound services documentation..which is why I'm here :)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot this :(

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```